# No TIME_WAIT connections, why?

Tags: linux, tcp, time-wait

If I have sysctl tw_reuse=0 and tw_recycle=0, and netstat doesn't report any TIME_WAIT connections, that means...? It's local network connections between two servers, A -> B, A has TIME_WAIT connections to B in netstat, but B to A not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the side of the connection that closes the communication can be in TIME_WAIT state, see the relevant [UNIX Socket FAQ](http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=2941) sequence diagram.

> Remember that TCP guarantees all data
>   transmitted will be delivered, if at
>   all possible. When you close a socket,
>   the server goes into a TIME_WAIT
>   state, just to be really really sure
>   that all the data has gone through.